# CORS not working in a IIS Server without SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, iis, cors

I have a .net core API application but CORS doesnt work if its deployed in a IIS server that don't have an SSL Certification

Aside from registering an SSL certificate in our server is there another solution for this?

Note: we have already specified to allow all origin/method/credentials/header in the code behind

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but if you don't protect the communication with https, isn't this sort of like showing up to a house fire with a garden hose?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same with my problem.

I've added these in my Startup.cs but it doesn't work.

```
        app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials());
```

and

```
  app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials());
```

I even added an OptionsMiddleware but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did the same as well when we have deployed in a IIS with ssl certificate it works

but without ssl ceritification it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue, but it resolved by this:-

```
<system.webServer>    
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>
```